# Alternative of for loops(optimization)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a sample Json as mentioned below

```
[{
    "Name": "Kim",
    "Details": {
        "Age": 43,
        "Gender": "Male",
        "Education": [{
                "Primary": "Xavier",
                "Percentage": 90,
                "subject": [{
                    "sub": "Math",
                    "Perf": "Good"

                }],
                "Marks": [{
                    "Mark": 90,
                    "Grade": "A"
                }]
            },
            {
                "Secondary": "Anthony",
                "Percentage": 98,
                "subject": [{
                    "sub": "Math",
                    "Perf": "Good"
                }],
                "Marks": [{
                    "Mark": 100,
                    "Grade": "S"
                }]
            },
            {
                "Bachelor": "Boston",
                "Percentage": 90,
                "subject": [{
                    "sub": "Computers",
                    "Perf": "Good"
                }],
                "Marks": [{
                    "Mark": 90,
                    "Grade": "A"
                }]
            },
            {

                "PostGrad": "Boston",
                "Percentage": 90,
                "subject": [{
                    "sub": "CNN",
                    "Perf": "Good"
                }],
                "Marks": [{
                    "Mark": 90,
                    "Grade": "A"
                }]   
            }]
    }

}]
```

form this I need to fetch the sub and Mark only from the entire Json.

I got the necessary output but the concern is I have utilised multiple for loops, below mentioned is my approch to fetch sub and marks,

```
import json
sampleJson = open('C:\\Users\\SampleJson.json')
sampleJsonData = json.loads(sampleJson.read())

resArray=[]
for i in range(len(sampleJsonData)):
    for j in range(len(sampleJsonData[i]["Details"])):
       for k in range(len(sampleJsonData[i]["Details"]["Education"])):
           for l in range(len(sampleJsonData[i]["Details"]["Education"])):
                for y in range(len(sampleJsonData[i]["Details"]["Education"][l]["subject"])):
                    sub = (sampleJsonData[i]["Details"]["Education"][l]["subject"][y]["sub"])
                for z in range(len(sampleJsonData[i]["Details"]["Education"][l]["Marks"])):
                    marks = sampleJsonData[i]["Details"]["Education"][l]["Marks"][z]["Mark"]
```

by any means is there any possibility that I could reduce the usage of for loops to nil.

I need to use those sub and Mark values further, as a temp measure stored the values in different variables.

I'm relatively very new to python, Please help me on this. Thanks

Comment: Since your code works, and seemingly doesn't take too long to run, maybe you actually want a [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)? Although I'd say, unless you're having performance issues, it's usually not worth trying to optimize something that's already working fine.

Comment: thanks @RandomDavis for your time, Was just curious and eager to know about different possibilities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Assuming the data consists of a list containing one single dictionary as per your example, it could look like this:

```
[(i['subject'][0]['sub'], i['Marks'][0]['Mark']) for i in sampleJsonData[0]['Details']['Education']]
```

Output:

```
[('Math', 90), ('Math', 100), ('Computers', 90), ('CNN', 90)]
```

Comment: this works fine,
just out of curiosity what would be the modification if there where multiple objects in the subject array, Something like this--> "subject": [{
  "sub": "Math",
  "Perf": "Good"

 },
 {
  "sub": "Sci",
  "Perf": "Averge"
 }, {
  "sub": "Eco",
  "Perf": "Good"
 }
],

Comment: In that case you'd have to include a second loop that iterates the items within `subject`. Because `subject` and `Mark` are separate lists, you could access the items by index number, eg. `[(i['subject'][n]['sub'], i['Marks'][n]['Mark']) for i in sampleJsonData[0]['Details']['Education'] for n in range(len(i['subject']))]`. Cf [nested list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions).

Comment: This does the job, Thanks for your time